# JavaScript callback functionality failure

Tags: javascript, function, html, callback, slider

I'm trying to implement the slider functionality I found [here](http://www.frequency-decoder.com/2010/11/18/unobtrusive-slider-control-html5-input-range-polyfill). However, I can't seem to get the `callback` functionality to work correctly. The page that I'm attempting to get it to work on is very simple in that I'm only trying to get it to call a function when the slider value changes: http://dev.itap.purdue.edu/dev/sandbox/jfish/slider.html.

I'm assuming I've made some simple javascript error but without much documentation I'm kind of stuck at this point. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an error on line 446 of the `fd-slider.js` function, where it tries to call each callback function `func.call(inp, cbObj);`

The `cbObj` variable is undefined, so the callbacks are not being called. I fixed this by updating those few lines, just to define that var.

```
for(var i = 0, func; func = callbacks[type][i]; i++) {
    var cbObj = null;
    func.call(inp, cbObj);
};
```

I couldn't find the callback object definition anywhere in the code.

Answer (score 2):

the callback should point to a function, like the code bellow

```
callbacks:{"move":[doAlert]}
```

but instead, you are pointing to the result of the function when you use the `()` at the end of `doAlert`. Thats why it is showing the alert when you load the page

Comment: I've made the change you suggested here, http://dev.itap.purdue.edu/dev/sandbox/jfish/slider2.html . However, it seems to still not call the function. I've also tried change the callback from 'move' to 'update' and 'change' with no success.

Comment: I think you should not remove the []s as the doc says that callback should be a hash with the callback type and an **Array** of functions.

Comment: I checked the doc again and the slider source a bit... the doc says `move` is  `Called whenever the drag handle moves position during an animation.`.. try use "finalise" instead of "move" for the callback key

Comment: Did you reverte the code there? I refreshed the page and the doAlert() thing is there again...

Answer (score 1):

Try this?

```
callbacks:{"move":function(){ doAlert(); }}
```

Comment: I'm not getting any errors, but it doesn't seem to be calling the function. http://dev.itap.purdue.edu/dev/sandbox/jfish/slider4.html

Comment: Did you try using `move` without the quotes?

Answer (score 0):

the code must be

```
callbacks:{"move":[doAlert]}
```

Comment: Still having issues: http://dev.itap.purdue.edu/dev/sandbox/jfish/slider3.html I'm getting actual javascipt errors now.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. this should solve your problem:

```
callbacks:{change:[doalert]}
```

Know that this library automatically passes through values so if you write your doalert function like

```
function(fdevent){alert(fdevent.value)}
```

your alert will say the value your slider is at.

read Callback functions http://www.frequency-decoder.com/2010/11/18/unobtrusive-slider-control-html5-input-range-polyfill/